# Actualizar un JTextArea en un JFrame desde datos provenientes de un Thread

Tags: java

Tengo un `JTextArea` en un `JFrame` y desde esta clase se abre un hilo que crea unos datos que necesito que se pasen al `JTextArea` cuando en el hilo ocurre una determinada acción. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Para que podamos ayudarte agrega el código que tienes hasta el momento. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En cuestion a los hilos o threads en java del JVM o asynctask en android se puede implementar un metodo propio de los JTextArea el cual permite que cualquier texto que se le envie lo vaya agrupando como si fuese una terminal de comandos, si lo que quieres es poder observar en forma de logs lo que va pasando en tus hilos por un jTextArea debes llamar el objeto jTextArea y con ayuda del metodo appened puedes ir copilando lo que pasa, deberia quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
private final static String newline = "\n";
...
textArea.append(text + newline);
```

Para que funcione dicho campo debe ser una variable global del sistema con el fin de que cualquier hilo lo pueda encontrar para ello cuando cree el campo debe dejarlo public y la instancia que ejecuta dicho metodo debe manejar el patron de diseño de software singleton.

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido :)